# PDFSharp working in editor but not in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.drawing, pdfsharp

This is a xpost from https://answers.unity.com/questions/1548350/pdfsharp-working-in-editor-but-not-in-build.html.

I'm working on a project in Unity and from within the build I need to be able to export data to a pdf.

For the export to PDF I'm using [PDFSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pdfsharp/1.32.3057) version 1.32.3057.

The player settings are as follows:
 - Unity 2018.1.0f2
 - Scripting Runtime Version: .NET 4.x Equivalent
 - Scripting Backend: Mono
 - Api Compatibility Level: .NET Standard 2.0

To produce the PDF, I use the following code:

```
string in_img = "C:\\test.jpg"
string out_pdf = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();

page.Height = XUnit.FromInch(26.67f);
page.Width = XUnit.FromInch(15f);
page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;

using (XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)) {
    using (XImage image = XImage.FromFile(in_img)) {
        gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 3840, 2160);
    }
}

doc.Save(out_pdf);
doc.Close();
```

Running the code in the editor produces a PDF as expected.

Building the code and running the build, however, results in the following error:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics:gfx' (12) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000047 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) assembly:System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Drawing.Graphics member:(null) signature:<none>
  at PdfExport.Start () [0x00077] in C:\...\Unity PDF Test\Assets\PdfExport.cs:27
```

I already searched on Google and Stackoverflow to find a clue to fix the error. Until now without success. I hope someone can point me into the right direction.

What is the cause of the error? And what do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: What platform are you building for?

Comment: I'm building on windows 10 and the target platform is Windows 10 64bit

Comment: I am getting same error